# Is it possible to store arrays in a custom field?

Tags: custom-field, post-meta, array

If I understand correctly, custom fields work like this:

```
key(string/int) => value(string/int)
```

Is it possible to define a custom field like this?

```
key(string/int) => value(array (string/int, string/int))
```

I want to use such a structure for storing a series of quotations in [quote, source] format, thinking that it would minimize potential input error compared with, say, str_splitting a single value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, either by code:

```
$demo = array('value1','value2','value3');
update_post_meta($post_id,'meta_key',$demo);
```

Or simply using the custom fields UI, add ass many values as you want one at a  time and make sure they all have the same meta_key.

Comment: If you use the UI and use the same key they get stored seperately though, so wouldn't really address what's being asked. You can of course use arrays on a single entry, you just have to store and retrieve that data yourself - because the WP custom field UI only deals with basic string key => value pairs.

Comment: So it is possible, but the UI isn't designed for it. Thanks for your help. I'll look into extending it with a plugin...

Comment: @t31os: they get stored separately, but if you call them using `get_post_meta($post->ID,'meta_key');` you will get an array of values.

Comment: @bainternet: Yes sure you will, but it stores them seperately, which is not the desired behaviour in relation to this question, or maybe it is and i'm just reading the question differently. ;-)

Comment: the question was really about UI, I guess - can I offer the user a custom field called 'quotation' that collects two bits of information, 'quote' and 'source', and have them stored thus: `('quote' => 'veni vidi vici', 'source' => 'julius caesar')`